# Recursively remove blank object and array from json object using loadsh in angular 2

Tags: angular, lodash

I am try to remove all blank object and array object subsequently from my json object using lodash in angular2 but not parse properly in object.

**My Json Object:**

```
{
  "personal": {
    "strenths": {},
    "books": [{},{},{"Perority1": "Test","level": ""},{"Perority2": "","level": ""},{"courses": [{},{},{}]}]
  },
  "eduction": [{},{},[{}]]
};
```

Try to remove using method

```
clean(obj) {
     console.log("Enter in a Clean() Method::::");
     Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
         if ($.isArray(obj[key])) {
             obj[key] = $.remove(obj[key], function(n) {
                 if ($.isObject(n) && (n === null || n === undefined || $.isEmpty(n))) {
                     return false;
                 } else {
                     return true;
                 }
             });
             console.log("After Change Array:::::" + JSON.stringify(obj[key]));
             if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined || $.isEmpty(obj[key])) {
                 delete obj[key];
             } else {
                 this.clean(obj[key]);
             }

         } else if ($.isObject(obj[key])) {

             if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined || $.isEmpty(obj[key])) {
                 delete obj[key];
             } else {
                 this.clean(obj[key]);
             }
         }
     });
     return obj;
 }
```

**My Output:**

```
{"personal":{"books":[{"Perority1":"Test","level":""},{"Perority2":"","level":""},{}]},"eduction":[null]}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{"personal":{"books":[{"Perority1":"Test","level":""},{"Perority2":"","level":""}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a complicated recursion, and altering tje object inside that, You can stringify the Object, and let you callback (the 2nd parameter of `JSON.parse`) do the recursion while parsin it from string, to remove a property simply return undefined;

```js
var data = {
  "personal": {
    "strenths": {},
    "books": [{},{},{"Perority1": "Test","level": ""},{"Perority2": "","level": ""},{"courses": [{},{},{}]}]
  },
  "eduction": [{},{},[{}]]
};

data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), function(k, v){
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        var fArr = v.filter(e=>e);
        return fArr.length && fArr || undefined;
    } else if(typeof(v) === "object" && !Object.keys(v).length) {
        return undefined;
    } else {return v};
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

However the code can be better, I just wrote on the fly on basis of your requirement.